# Select all rows where array contains values from a given list in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with an integer array column. I want to select all rows where contains at least one int value from a given list.

E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table where (111) = ANY (columarray)
```

returns all rows where columnarray contains 111.

Now I want select all rows where columnarray contains 111 or/and 222. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM table where (111,222) = ANY (columnarray)
```

that doesnt work. It returns an error

> Error: ERROR: operator does not exist: record = integer
>     Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
>     Position: 45
>   SQLState:  42883
>   ErrorCode: 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the array overlap operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM table 
WHERE ARRAY[111, 222] && columnarray;
```

Comment: Do you know how i can parameterize the ARRAY values wit JPA? I try to use a NativeQuery. ARRAY:values and setParameter('values', valuesArray) doesnt work.