# finding a given item value in an array of a given column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

`mTable`:

```
  |id     | text[] mVals        |  

  |1      | {"a,b"}             |
  |2      | {"a"}               |        
  |3      | {"b"}               |
```

I'd like a query to return both rows `{a,b},{b}` If I specify only b, but, it doesn't really return the row having atleast one of the specified values and only returns rows with the value specified.

[I have tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499706/select-all-rows-where-array-contains-values-from-a-given-list-in-postgres):

```
SELECT mVals
FROM mTable 
WHERE ARRAY['a'] && columnarray;  -- Returns only {'a'}
```

[Also tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value):

```
SELECT mVals 
FROM mTable 
WHERE mVals && '{"a"}'; -- Returns only {'a'}
```

Nothing seems to be working as it should. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to me it looks is working as expected, recreating your case with

```
create table test(id int, mvals text[]);
insert into test values(1, '{a}');
insert into test values(2, '{a,b}');
insert into test values(3, '{b}');
```

A query similar to the 1st one you posted works

```
SELECT mVals
FROM test 
WHERE ARRAY['a'] && mvals;
```

Results

```
 mvals
-------
 {a}
 {a,b}
(2 rows)
```

and with `b` instead of `a`

```
 mvals
-------
 {a,b}
 {b}
(2 rows)
```

**P.S.**: you should probably use the contain operator `@>` to check if a value (or an array) is contained in another array

Comment: To anyone coming across this, I was actually string_agg(column) instead of array_agg, so my arrays actually had been coming out like this all along {"a, b"}, really wasted all that time, t